# Revit room boundingbox and levels offset

Tags: bounding-box, revit-api

For our Revit addin (in c#), I need to get some room boundingbox (based on model values)
For this I use element.Get_BoundingBox function, but it seems , the Z coordinates do not respect the base and limit offsets of the room
for example, a room has a level to 0 coordinate, a base offest equal to -400.0, in this case the box.min.z value is 0 in place of -400.0

is it normal and I am missing some logical aspect , or is it a Revit problem ?

How can I find the right values (I know how to compute them by recalculating from levels and offsets , but I prefer if I can have the result by a direct api call)

thanks in advance

Luc

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a [minimal reproducible case](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b), e.g., a model with one single room and a macro that reproduces the behaviour you describe. Please also add an illustrative image showing the room geometry and the level. If it is true, I will report it as an issue to the development team. Thank you.

Comment: How can I send you a rvt file and a demo c# project ?

Comment: There are thousands of different ways. You could create a thread for this in the Revit API discussion forum and attach a zip file to that: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api/bd-p/160/. You could upload it to a file transfer service such as wetransfer and post a link to it here: https://wetransfer.com/

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning I also had the problem with offset bounding boxes to the level. After some searching I found the value.
It is the difference between "Elevation" and "ProjectElevation".
You can easily read them out at any level using the RevitAPI.

https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/895ef506-bfea-cc4e-31f8-aad2af6672e4.htm
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/b5d48a18-4aa9-7457-7a6a-6d4966eaf77f.htm